# Dynamically changing sub-menu 's value

Tags: c++, mfc

I am developing a code where I have a menu ,submenu ( which is dynamically changing). I would like to get the value of this dynamically changing value of the sub-menu.How can I do that?

Comment: What is the framework that you're developing on, and what platform?

Comment: at least you should retag tour question

Comment: I had developed the menu,submenu using  MFC's CMenu. I am developing in c++.

Comment: How do I develop this?Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Explore documentation the OnInitMenuPopup of your CMainFrame class.